# Changing data source for audio playback using existing MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to use the same media player but change the data source. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public void pickFile1() {
       initMediaPlayer("myfile1.mp3");
    }

    public void pickFile2() {
       initMediaPlayer("myfile2.mp3");
    }

    private void initMediaPlayer(String mediafile) {
    // Setup media player, but don't start until user clicks button!
    try {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();   // so can change data source etc.
        }
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(mediafile); 
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
    mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);  // Keep playing when screen goes off!
}
```

I just call this when I want to change to a new mediafile.  It doesn't appear to be changing the data source successfully though.  First question:  is it possible to do it this way, or do I have to release the media player and create a new one for each new file?  If it is possible, then why isn't my code working right?

Edit: well, releasing and recreating the media player isn't doing it either!  It just keeps playing the same song!?!? How is that even possible?  New idea -- create a different media player for each track, is that really what I have to do here?  Is this a bug in Android perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did get a really good answer for this. I think it might be something funny that happens in the emulator.  What I have done that is working great for me, is to download the files to the external SD card and play them from there.  That changes the code slightly to this:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/";
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + mediafile);
```

the rest remains the same.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure to stop and reset mediaplayer before changing datasource. 
On more important thing when you stop it calls

> onCompletion

.. So do check what you are doing in this method.  Then call

```
mplayer.setDataSource(audioPath);
mplayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mplayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've actually had this same problem with assets today, and I know the fix.

The problem is that the assets are stored as one big chunk of data rather than actually as a bunch of individual files on a real file system somewhere. So, when you get an `assetfiledescriptor`, it points both to a file, but also has an offset and a length. If you just point `mediaplayer` at the `assetfiledescriptor` itself, it always plays the first media file in your assets folder (or something).

If you do this:
`mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());`

then it plays the right file.

Comment: Very interesting, when I have a chance I'm going to give your suggestion a try!  I hadn't ever heard that about assets -- could you put in a link to a relevant bit of documentation about this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You declare `private String mediafile="my.mp3";` then you use `AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(mediafile);` but at no point (from the code you posted) do you change the value of `mediafile`.
 I would recommend putting `mediafile = theNextFile;` onthe line before `afd = getAssets().openFd(mediafile);` where `theNextFile` would likely refer to a file on the sd card that the user chose before clicking said button.
I'm not sure how to manage getting the file names from sd card, but I'd think using a `startActivityForResult` would be one way to do it.

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't include that part from my code so my sample is flawed.  I will update accordingly -- unfortunately that is not the reason my code is not working.  I have verified with debugger that the mediafile has a different file name in it even though the original file continues to play.  In my case, file is included in assets folder so I can access as shown in my code.