# How to play/stop/play again using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio

I have a button when clicked it plays an audio, and while it is playing I can pause it and replay it again and so forth. I have a shake event, where I want to play the audio on shake and replay it when device is shaken again (by first stopping the audio, calling `stopAudio`?)

I have the following code:

```
llBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button);
llBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LL WAS CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //IF AUDIO IS NOT PLAYING... PLAY AUDIO
        if (tvPS.getText() == "Stop Phrase!") {
            StopAudio();
        }
        else {
            PlayAudio();
        }
    }
});
//the same button is clicked to stop, it is currently setting to Pause.
public void StopAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvPS.setText("Play Phrase!");
    }

public void PlayAudio() {
    //stopPlaying(mediaPlayer);
    tvPS.setText("Stop Phrase!");

    inResId = getResources().getIdentifier("play" , "raw", getPackageName());

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), inResId);
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvPS.setText("Play Phrase!");
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    });
}
...
public void onShake() {
    // Do stuff!
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Motion detected", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        PlayAudio();
    }
}
```

How can I modify the code above to handle Play, and then stop if stopped in the middle and then able to replay it again.

The button click works but I am creating a new instance each time and not recycling. When the device is shaken, it plays the audio twice instead of just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create the `MediaPlayer` in onCreate of the context and not in some listener, and don't forget to release it when done, since it consumes a lot of resources,

```
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;
```

Next thing, stop the audio using the `stop()` function instead of the `pause()` on completion of the song.

#### Steps

If you are using a service/activity to play a video create a MediaPlayer instance before it's usage begins, likely in onCreate.

Later use that instance to play/pause/stop the media.

In the onStop of the Service/Activity release the MediaPlayer instance.

Update your playMusic() function to use the MediaPlayer instance you just created, also in the listener use stop() instead of pause()

#### To change track of an existing MediaPlayer instance

You can use this:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()+"/";

mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + mediafile);
```

Link: [Changing data source for audio playback using existing MediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244338/changing-data-source-for-audio-playback-using-existing-mediaplayer)

Comment: I have multiple audio I am playing which is not listed here the resID is different. Can i create a blank mediaPlayer and use that across the activity?

Comment: I've have edited the answer, have a look